# Azure Configuration Error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure

I am testing Azure and I keep running into this problem - I have no idea if anyone else has experienced something similar. Locally, the solution is working fine - no problems at all, but when I put it into the cloud - I just keep getting this error ?

Any Ideas?

Azure Configuration Error type="Microsoft.Samples.ServiceHosting.AspProviders.TableStorageSessionStateProvider"

Comment: Have you added the dll as a reference? It sounds like it's failing to find that dll.

Comment: hey matt, added as project references. Try to add as dll not project (but, project copies own dll to "recepient") - any ideas?

Comment: i tried adding it directly, still get the error .....

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like this got answered on the Windows Azure forum: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsazure/thread/454e0186-241f-4dad-a67a-43a3774c1cec

Comment: Hey Steve, enjoyed your talk on Azure!